# Creating MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue throws FormatException

Tags: c#

I am creating an instance of `MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue` like this:

```
var m = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=acrcloud***copyright***2015***8d467c7c10a7062");
```

It throws a `FormatException`, so I guess the string that I passed doesn't follow the standard convention. It's supposed to be the content type that my client API requires. I then need to add it to my `HttpClient` to make the API call like so:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(m);
```

My first question is, how can I fix the string that I passed so that the format is correct?

My second question is, is it possible to set the content type to this string, even though it is not formatted correctly?

**EDIT**

To clarify, I'm trying to do the equivalent of this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=acrcloud***copyright***2015***8d467c7c10a7062";
```

But with using the `HttpClient` class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fails becaus Multipart/form-type is not a media type, but a content type. The content is defined by providing the HTTP send method (GetAsync, PostAsync, ...) with the proper HttpContent object. For multipart contents a special HttpContent class exists which allows the encapsulation of multiple HttpContents. So basically it goes like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("acrcloud***copyright***2015***8d467c7c10a7062");
  content.Add(new StringContent("value"), "key");
  content.Add(new StreamContent(stream)
  {
    Headers =
    {
      ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(DispositionTypeNames.Attachment) { Filename = "Filename.txt" }
    }
  }, "filekey");
  await PostAsync("http://www.example.com", content);
}
```

Comment: It breaks on this line `var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("acrcloud***copyright***2015***8d467c7c10a7062");` unless I remove the asterisks...is there anyway to keep them like I did in my `HttpWebRequest` example?

Comment: According to the relevant standard https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1341 section 7.2.1 the only valid characters for the boundary are numbers, ASCII letters, ALPHA / "'" / "(" / ")" / "+"  / "_" / "," / "-" / "." / "/" / ":" / "=" / "?" and " ". So HttpClient seems to be more strict about this than WebRequest.

Comment: Addendum: The current standard is https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-5.1.1, but stating the same boundary rules that the asterisk is unfortunately an invalid character.

Comment: Is there a function built-into C# that verifies if the boundary string is of correct format?

Comment: I don't think so. But you can easily write one yourself: bool IsValidBoundary(string boundary) { return !boundary.Except("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'()+_,-./:=? ").Any(); }